# Hide and unhide a view in Red language

Tags: window, red

I am trying following code to have a second view which can be hidden and shown again repeatedly while preserving values in its fields:

```
Red []

secondFstr: ""
secondshownonce: false
secondshowing: false

secondview: does [
    secondshownonce: true
    if not secondshowing [
      secondshowing: true
      view [ below
        text "second view"
        f2: field secondFstr []
        b3: button "Hide" [
            secondshowing: false
            unview ]]]]

view [ below
    text "first view"
    b1: button "Print f2 text" [
          either not secondshownonce 
            [print "not shown"]
            [print f2/text] ]
    b2: button "Show 2nd view" [secondview] ]
```

It works all right if 'hide' button is used for second view. But if the second view is closed by clicking 'x' at its top right corner, it cannot be shown again. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a way to hook into the close event?

Comment: on-close documentation is not available: http://www.red-by-example.org/index.html#0on-close . Also not there on this page: http://www.mycode4fun.co.uk/red-beginners-reference-guide or on https://doc.red-lang.org/en/view.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an handler to the `close` event on that child window, in order to reset your flag properly, like this:

```
view/options [
    below
    text "second view"
    f2: field secondFstr []
    b3: button "Hide" [
        secondshowing: false
        unview
    ]
][
    actors: object [
        on-close: func [face event][
            secondshowing: false
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: After closing second view by top right corner 'x', I cannot reopen it.  (It reopens if I use 'hide' button).

Comment: It works fine after replacing your second view code with the one I posted here. Didn't you try it?